# If event.target.value is empty then not appendChild into ul, how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, dom

**HTML and Javascript**

I would like to create element and remove those I did it But when input field is empty the blank Li display after hit enter. I don't want to display when input field blank. How can I do this?

Codepen Link https://codepen.io/afsar-uddin/pen/abBBQbo

```
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="list_itme">
                        <input type="text" id="nameField" placeholder="Write something and hit enter..." >
                        <ul id="nameList"></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            let nameField = document.querySelector('#nameField')
            let ul = document.querySelector('#nameList')
        
            nameField.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
                
                if(event.keyCode === 13) {
                    let name = event.target.value
                    createLi(ul, name)
                    event.target.value = ''
                } 
                
            })
        
            function createLi(ul, name) {
                let listItem = document.createElement('li')
                listItem.innerHTML = name
                
                let span = document.createElement('span')
                span.innerHTML = 'X'
                listItem.appendChild(span)
                span.className = 'right'
        
                span.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    ul.removeChild(listItem)
                })
        
                ul.appendChild(listItem)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `if(name.length === 0) return;`

```
function createLi(ul, name) {
            if(name.length === 0) return;
            let listItem = document.createElement('li')
            listItem.innerHTML = name
            
            let span = document.createElement('span')
            span.innerHTML = 'X'
            listItem.appendChild(span)
            span.className = 'right'
    
            span.addEventListener('click', function(){
                ul.removeChild(listItem)
            })
    
            ul.appendChild(listItem)
        }
```